# Wrapping asyncio Stream with TLS or SSL

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, server, python-asyncio

I'm making a python TCP multiuser-based server. I'm using the standard `socket` lib in the client-side, and asyncio streams in the server-side by converting the socket object  into streams after establishing the connection with the client with a code looks like this.

The server-side code:

```
async def runSocket(self, server_sokcet):
    server_sokcet.listen(1)
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = await asyncio.get_event_loop().sock_accept(server)
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(sock=client_socket)
        data = await reader.read(1024)
        response = self.generateResponse(data.decode('utf-8'))
        await writer.write(response.encode('utf-8'))
```

And this is how the client-side code looks like:

```
def postRequest(data, hostname, port):
    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    server.connect((hostname, port))
    server.send(data.enocode('utf-8'))
    response = server.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    return response
```

Everything was awesome, until I started to use `ssl` library to wrap the connection with SSL or TLS. I found that whenever I wrap the socket of the server and convert it into an asyncio stream, and use the read method on the `StreamReader` object, the data I receive from the client isn't decrypted. I just get some random bytes that doesn't even accept the `utf-8` decoding.
These are the adjustments I made to wrap the connection:

Server:

```
async def runSocket(self, server_sokcet):
    server_sokcet.listen()
    # the ssl context
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile="tls\\server_certificate.pem", keyfile="tls\\server_private_key.pem")
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = await asyncio.get_event_loop().sock_accept(server)
        # Wrapping with ssl
        encrypted_client_socket = context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=True)
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(sock=encrypted_client_socket)
        data = await reader.read(1024)
        response = self.generateResponse(data.decode('utf-8'))
        await writer.write(response.encode('utf-8'))
```

Client:

```
def postRequest(data, hostname, port):
    # the ssl context
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.check_hostname = False
    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    # Wrapping with ssl
    encrypted_server  = context.wrap_socket(server, server_hostname=hostname)
    encrypted_server.connect((hostname, port))
    encrypted_server.send(data.enocode('utf-8'))
    response = encrypted_server.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    return response
```

I think the `StreamReader.read` returns the raw data without even decrypting them.
any ideas guys?

Comment: so what? I have been waiting for 13 days now.

Comment: I appreciate you guys, please give me a hand